# Odoo how to access product.qty_available as portal user

Tags: product, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

We are trying to add the the stock of our products so it's visible to our users.

our code would just simply be:

```
<t t-esc="product.qty_available"/>
```

As a Internal User this works but a public user/portal gives a 403 error:

> 403: Forbidden
>
> The page you were looking for could not be authorized.
>
> Maybe you were looking for one of these popular pages ?

I know I should alter the access rights for users but I don't know which one to change.

Can somebody tell me what I should do to make that variable visible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't there a group portal users with access rights for this?

Comment: I was logged in as a portal user and it didn't work so they don't had access rights.

Comment: I am not an expert in this but I found "base.group_portal" as group_id in the security rules for a module that uses portal. You probably have to add a security rule for base.group_portal for this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the access restriction by using [sudo()](https://docs.huihoo.com/odoo/developer/12.0/reference/orm.html#altering-the-environment):

```
<t t-esc="product.sudo().qty_available"/>
```

This will change the user to SUPERUSER only for this case, without having to change the access rights for that column.